# Rcode print function is not printing the value of the variable

Tags: r

I can't get `print()` to work (using it to debug) so that this:

```
EK <- read.csv("data23_09.csv")
line_values <- EK[1, ]
print(line_values[1])
print("why")
```

Yields this:

```
> EK <- read.csv("data23_09.csv")
> line_values <- EK[1, ]
> print(line_values[1])
> print("why")
[1] "why"
```

I can see that `EK` is populated:

[image]

But `print(line_values[1])` does not show what's in `line_values[1]` in the console.

Adding information in response to comments:

```
EK <- read.csv("data23_09.csv")
line_values <- EK[2, ]
print(str(line_values[1]))
print(str(line_values[1]))
```

Yield:

```
> EK <- read.csv("data23_09.csv")
> line_values <- EK[2, ]
> print(str(line_values[1]))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ S: num 2.5
NULL
> print(str(line_values[1]))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ S: num 2.5
NULL
```

[image: Line value]

Edit: getAnywhere("print.data.frame") yields:

```
> getAnywhere("print.data.frame")
A single object matching ‘print.data.frame’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:base
  registered S3 method for print from namespace base
  namespace:base
with value

function (x, ..., digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
    row.names = TRUE, max = NULL) 
{
    n <- length(row.names(x))
    if (length(x) == 0L) {
        cat(sprintf(ngettext(n, "data frame with 0 columns and %d row", 
            "data frame with 0 columns and %d rows"), n), "\n", 
            sep = "")
    }
    else if (n == 0L) {
        print.default(names(x), quote = FALSE)
        cat(gettext("<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)\n"))
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(max)) 
            max <- getOption("max.print", 99999L)
        if (!is.finite(max)) 
            stop("invalid 'max' / getOption(\"max.print\"): ", 
                max)
        omit <- (n0 <- max%/%length(x)) < n
        m <- as.matrix(format.data.frame(if (omit) 
            x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE]
        else x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE))
        if (!isTRUE(row.names)) 
            dimnames(m)[[1L]] <- if (isFALSE(row.names)) 
                rep.int("", if (omit) 
                  n0
                else n)
            else row.names
        print(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right, max = max)
        if (omit) 
            cat(" [ reached 'max' / getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
                n - n0, "rows ]\n")
    }
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000023b84459120>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Did you `knitr` your `Rmd`? `print(line_values[1])`does not show whats behind `line_values[1]` in your console?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that print(line_values[1])does not show whats behind line_values[1] in the console, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Does `data(iris); line_values2 <- iris[1L, ]; print(line_values2[[1]])`, which should correspond to `iris[1L, 1L]`, print something to your console?

Comment: Yes that prints '5.1'

Comment: What do `str(line_values)` and `str(line_values[1])` show?

Comment: @user2554330 I added a new code extract and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your results, but I'd guess this is caused by RStudio.  There are options to print dataframes using `View`, and I'd guess you have accidentally enabled one of those.

You may be able to diagnose this by executing

```
getAnywhere("print.data.frame")
```

(which should show only `base::print.data.frame`) or by looking in the Add-ins menu.

Comment: I updated the question with the result,. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: It's showing the normal output, the same as on my system.  It's something else, but I'm running out of ideas.   Not sure my answer deserves the checkmark...